# Crossrider - Chrome Web Store: Developer Account Suspended

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crossrider

I've created browser extension using crossrider almost a year ago. It was working ok, till this morning I received an email saying: "Your developer account has been suspended." because: "At least one of your items has been removed from the store because it did not comply with our policies or terms of service." And I have only one item.

Moreover, my site has an install button (for this extension). And now google marked my site as malware and nobody can access it without seeing big malware warning and clicking on I Agree several times.

I guess google started using some new tools that mark crossrider library as malware. Please advise.

Comment: And why are you asking here? Specifically, what _is_ your question that is [within Stack Overflow's scope](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? You should be talking to Google CWS support and Crossrider support; even if they indicate SO as a support option, it's not a technical question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a technical or theoretical programming question, but rather an account support incident.

Comment: I'm asking here since it what was said on crossrider's Facebook page. At this stage we still don't know whether it's a technical question or not. There is a malware false positive and not clear what causing it. It could be some specific code in people's extension.

Comment: I'd think that http://crossrider.com/developers looks more promising than their Facebook page.  Even if it is a technical question, without more to go on, it probably won't be on topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday after receiving the suspension mail I've submitted Developer Appeal to Chrome Web Store. Now I received an answer:

"Dear Developer,

Thank you for submitting your appeal to the Chrome Web Store.

We've carefully reviewed your case and will immediately re-instate your developer account.

Your apps and extensions will not be automatically re-published, so you will need to upload them again into the Web Store. When uploading your items again, please ensure that you continue to stay in compliance with our Developer Terms of Service and Program Policies."

So, submit the appeal and hope for the best.

Comment: As it turns out, it's not the end. As they mentioned in the mail, I had to upload the extension again. One day after uploading my account got suspended again. I responded to the mail above, three days passed and got no response. Thus, submitting another appeal.

Comment: After the second appeal my account was restored. I didn't have to upload the plugin again an everything seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your story, I've got a similar case going on right now - hoping for the best =)